# Java ImageIO PNG Encoding Incorrectly?

Tags: java, png, javax.imageio

I've been trying to encode some data (represented as array of byte values 0-255) in a PNG image format with Java. The data is read out using HTML canvas element getImageData() method in JavaScript (similar to this: http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/compression-using-canvas-and-png.html).

However, the output data is not always identical to the input. Some of the values appear to differ from the input. It seems to work encoding as an image 1 pixel high, and is only incorrect for an image with multiple rows. I had the idea it could be caused by the line-by-line filtering for PNG images somehow but don't really know.

It seems that each incorrect value is only ever wrong by 1 or 2.

Here's the Java code but I'm wondering if it could also be an issue with the ImageIO api, in particular its PNG encoder?

```
public static File encodeInPng(byte[] data, String filename) throws java.io.IOException{
    int width = (int)Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(data.length));
    int height = (int)Math.ceil((double)data.length/width);

    BufferedImage bufImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for (byte b : data) {
        bufImg.getRaster().setPixel(x, y, new int[]{b&0xFF});
        x++;
        if (x == width) {
            x = 0;
            y ++;
        }
    }

    File f = new File(filename);
    ImageIO.write(bufImg, "png", f);

    return f;
}
```

**Edit:** The problem only appears for PNG files over a certain size (around 50 kB, or possibly 256x256px).

Comment: um, I'm thinking that you really don't want to tag JavaScript. Deleted.

Comment: `y = 0;` seems like an error. Maybe you meant `x = 0;`?

Comment: You're right, although the original code was correct (I changed some var names when posting to make more readable).

Comment: Are you sure `width * height` is *always* `== data.length` in this case? Are you always creating `data` arrays to fit a square image (2x2, 3x3, .., NxN)? Otherwise, your code for calculating `width` and `height` is wrong.

Comment: @haraldK: the image size width*height should always be >= datasize, and it seems the OP chose a square for convenience. Unless `Math.sqrt` does some *really* nasty rounding down square roots, the calculations seem correct. However! Even if the image size is off, it would not show what the OP reports. All a too small image size should do is show some data loss at the end.

Comment: @Jongware: Well, if the image dimensions doesn't matter, as long as the data buffer is large enough, ok... But then, why not just encode in a single line, as the OP said worked fine?

Comment: The canvas element used to read back the data does not seem to be able to handle images exceeding a certain size in either the x or y dimension. Using a 2D image will help to reduce the maximum dimension (plus is more visually appealing).

Comment: The problem only appears for PNG files over a certain size (around 50 kB, or possibly 256x256px).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I discovered that the problem only occurred for images larger than 256x256. I did a bit of research and discovered existing (although different) problems that people had experienced in Chrome (with the canvas element and this size image). So I tried using Firefox, and no errors!

Seems like the Chrome canvas element is far from perfect.

*[Using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77]*

**Edit:**  Also, setting the chrome://flags "Disable accelerated 2D canvas" makes it work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations of dimensions is rather ugly, and some parts of the code could be slightly more efficient and clean - some polishing comes below. But your code seems basically correct, and it works for me. Can you pass an example where "output data is not identical to the input"?

```
public static File encodeInPng(byte[] data, String filename) 
         throws java.io.IOException {
    int width = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(data.length));
    int height = data.length / width;
    BufferedImage bufImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    int[] pix = new int[1];
    int pos = 0;
    for( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
        for( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
            pix[0] = data[pos++] & 0xFF;
            bufImg.getRaster().setPixel(x, y, pix);
        }
    }
    File f = new File(filename);
    ImageIO.write(bufImg, "png", f);
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Is it (slightly) safer to caluclate `height = (data.length+width-1) / width`? Then you are sure the destination buffer is large enough. Currently, if `data.length % width > 0`, you will miss an entire row, won't you? But yeah, I'd like to have a peek on a PNG with a simple message encoded as well.